# problem in !ispostback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have problem with !IspostBack 
i'm working with crystal report and i use (if not ispostback) to set X and in else to retrieve X 
the problem is its working properly in some pages and not working in others. 
this code sample.

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
     Session("VehicleStatusSelectionFormula") = SelectionFormula
Else
     SelectionFormula = Session("VehicleStatusSelectionFormula")
End If
```

note: is ("EnableViewStateMac="false") make if not ispostback doesn't work ?
beacause the page that doesn't work has this in page register

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ReportsVehicleStatusScript.aspx.vb" Inherits="ReportsVehicleStatusScript" **EnableViewStateMac="false"**  %>
```

please i need some help why its working in some pages and not in others ?

thanks.

finally I found the problem :
the problem like i said in last note with ("EnableViewStateMac="false") it make ispostback true all the time.

Comment: What method are you calling this code in?

Comment: And how are you setting SelectionFormula when not in a postback? (And if its just local to the page should it be session or viewstate?) Need a bit more context and a bit more detail about the nature of the failures i.e. what do you mean by "not working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the problem : the problem like i said in last note with ("EnableViewStateMac="false") it make ispostback true all the time

Comment: do you have a link to documentation where this is shown? I was unaware that setting this to false caused this and have never seen this happen